# Problem to read data from table that is inserted some data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, recordset, subform

I  have a sub-form and data isn't updated after insert into table from SQL Server to access table

I have MS Access application with some object (table, form, sub-form).
My sub-form record source is one of the tables and when I open form include sub-form data showed.

I connect to SQL Server and get some data from `dbo.telefone` and insert into my table (GetTelServer) after an event like click button, but new data isn't updated in sub-form despite I refresh or requery form or sub-form. I am really confused why this occurs?

```
Dim strSQL1 As String
Dim rst1, RstAccess As ADODB.Recordset
              strSQL1 = "SELECT * from dbo.telefone"
             Set rst1 = New ADODB.Recordset
                     With rst1
                        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
                        .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
                        .LockType = adLockOptimistic
                        .Open strSQL1, cn, adCmdText
                      End With
                Set RstAccess = New ADODB.Recordset
                RstAccess.Open "SELECT * from GetTelServer", cnAccess, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
                Do Until rst1.EOF
                        RstAccess.AddNew
                        RstAccess.Fields("Name").Value =         rst1.Fields("Name").Value
                        RstAccess.Fields("job").Value = rst1.Fields("job").Value
                        RstAccess.Update
                        rst1.MoveNext
                 Loop

      Me.Query_subform.Requery
      Me.Refresh
        RstAccess.Close
        Set RstAccess = Nothing
        cnAccess.Close
        Set cnAccess = Nothing
        Me.Query_subform.Form.RecordSource = "SELECT * from GetTelServer"
       'even 
        set Query_subform.Form.recordset= RstAccess
```

I have no idea why data doesn't come to my sub-form. Of course if reopen form everything is OK but I don't want to reopen form. I expected the sub-form data update immediately after insert into table

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need to refresh from the source data after you assign the recordsource to the subform.
Your last line does not look valid (if it was valid, recordset would have a capital letter once the syntax was validated), please comment it out.

Please add a new last line:

```
 Me.Query_subform.Refresh
```

Even a Me.Refresh may do it...
Then re-test.

Comment: Yes, aboat last line I  mean I even tested with (set Query_subform.Form.recordset= RstAccess), but it wasn't Ok. I have no Idea why, but apparently after inserting data we need close and open table for using new data, but what we do it?

Comment: That last line was never going to work, as a few lines above you have closed RstAccess.  
some suggestions:   
1.  after the line with Loop, put a new line with: rst1.Close

Comment: 2.  if the subform Recordsource is already set to "SELECT * from GetTelServer" then you don't need to re-set it in the third last line, instead, just put a line with Me.Query_subform.Refresh

Comment: read up about lock type optimistic - it is possible that the data you want to see has not yet arrived in the database... a different lock type may take a little longer, but ensure the data is available when you read it.